# How to see webpage from docker server over internet in win7

Tags: docker

How to see website of docker server from internet in win7?

install `docker toolbox` in `win7 64bit`
I can't access docker server from internet.

I can see webpage of native server in win7 from internet without any problem.

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL      SWARM   DO
CKER        ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1
8.06.1-ce

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  
CREATED
       STATUS              PORTS
NAMES
65b815ffa17c        richarvey/nginx-php-fpm   "docker-php-entrypoi"   4 hours ag
o         Up 4 hours          80/tcp, 443/tcp, 9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp
web
```

---

host (win7) <---> VM guest <---> docker container

I believe
adapter 1 `NAT` is `VM guest <---> docker container` part.
adapter 2 `host-only` is `host (win7) <---> VM guest` part.

so I can never connect docker container over outside internet in this setting.

**try 1**

If I try to change adapter 2 `bridge` from `host-only`, it will generate error or jump back to `host-only`.

[image]

[image]

**try 2**

change ip from windows' adapter

[image]

I change `VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2`

1 ) Go to Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network Connections
2 ) Right Click on `VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2` and select Properties
3 ) Select Internet Protocol Version 4(TCP/IPv4) and click Properties
4 ) click `obtain an IP address automatically`

[image]

result:

It generates a `VirtualBox Host-Only Network #3` adapter with original parameter...

```
$ docker-machine start default
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to create a network adapter. Some
times, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
(default) Found a new host-only adapter: "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
#3"
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a network adapter. S
ometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a dhcp server. Somet
imes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
(default) Waiting for an IP...
Machine "default" was started.
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.
```

**try 3**

1 ) Go to Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network Connections
2 ) Right Click on `VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2` and select Properties
3 ) Select Internet Protocol Version 4(TCP/IPv4) and click Properties
4 ) `Give to the adapter a static IP address` that is valid on your current real   network. Make sure the DNS is also valid so the container will be able to resolve domains on the Web

result: useless, just like **try 2**

[ref](https://forums.docker.com/t/bridge-with-docker-for-windows/30936/5)

**try 4**

...

---

**update**
ok, I know why.

I set my firewall wrong.
DMZ should be on host IP instead of VM IP.

Answer (score 0):

From your local

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER-ID> sh
```

Comment: I try to see the content from server, like a website or something... no _docker inside_